# 'x' not in list while iterating over list

Tags: python, for-loop, recursion, python-3.x, reddit

What I am attempting to do is iterate over a list of comments, remove the current comment that has been added to a value called `cText`, and if `cText` goes over 9000 characters make a recursive call into the same function and add it's returned value into `botComments`. I'm also attempting to merge the returned `botComments` list from a recursed function to the top-most `botComments` list with `botComments + repliesToComments(comments, author)` though I don't know if I'm doing anything right. Oddly, it also seems it can't find a comment in a list that for-sure has the comment throwing the exception I pasted below. I was horrible at recursion during my AP Comp-Sci class though I wish to learn what I'm doing wrong from whomever can fix my mess of code below. Thanks :)

Here's my current exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Josh\Desktop\bot.py", line 62, in <module>
    print(repliesToComments(submission.comments, submission.author.name))
  File "C:\Users\Josh\Desktop\bot.py", line 36, in repliesToComments
    botComments + repliesToComments(comments, author)
  File "C:\Users\Josh\Desktop\bot.py", line 39, in repliesToComments
    comments.remove(comment)
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

Here's my code:

```
def repliesToComments(comments, author):
    botComments = []
    multiReplies = False

    cText = "Here is a list of all the comments /u/" + author + ''' has submitted to top-level comments:
***
Original Comment | /u/''' + author + ''''s Reply
---------|---------
'''

    for comment in comments[:]:
        if (hasattr(comment, "replies")):
            for comment2 in comment.replies:
                if (hasattr(comment2, "author") and comment2.author.name == author):
                    oCommentLink = "[" + comment.body.replace("\n", "")[:50] + "](" + submission.permalink + "" + comment2.parent_id.replace("t1_", "") + ")..."
                    rCommentLink = "[" + comment2.body.replace("\n", "")[:50] + "](" + submission.permalink + "" + comment2.name.replace("t1_", "") + ")..."
                    if (len(cText) + len(oCommentLink + " | " + rCommentLink + "\n") > 9000): #Stop here to make sure we don't go over 10000 char limit!
                        multiReplies = True
                        cText += '''
***
[FAQ](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=wUGmE8X5) | Generated at ''' + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + " PST" + " | *This comment only shows a partial amount of OPs total replies due to character limit. The rest are shown in a reply to this comment.*"
                        botComments.append(cText)
                        botComments + repliesToComments(comments, author)
                        break
                    cText += oCommentLink + " | " + rCommentLink + "\n"
        comments.remove(comment)

    if (multiReplies == False):
        cText += '''
***
[FAQ](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=wUGmE8X5) | Generated at ''' + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + " PST"

    botComments.append(cText)
    return botComments
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling `repliesToComments()` recursively, but with the *exact same arguments*. This can only lead to problems.

Your recursive call is removing entries from the same list, and when it returns, *those entries will still be gone*. But because you loop over a *copy* of the list, your outer call won't be updated and try to remove comments the inner recursive call removed *already*.

Perhaps you wanted to call `repliesToComments()` for a different set of comments when recursing? I suspect you meant to call it for `comment.replies` instead?

Another problem your code has is that you *ignore* the return value of the recursive call:

```
botComments + repliesToComments(comments, author)
```

This adds the list `botComments` and the return value of the recursive call, creating a *new* list, which you then drop to the floor by not assigning it to a variable. You probably want to use:

```
botComments += repliesToComments(comments, author)
```

instead.

Comment: I mean to call `repliesToComments()` with a list of comments **not including** the ones I have already iterated over.

Comment: @Josh: and you'll still iterate over the *rest* after the call completes. That is your problem.

Comment: @Josh: say you have a list `['foo', 'bar', 'baz']` and removed `'foo'` already, then recurse for `['bar', 'baz']`, but the recursive call removes `'bar'` as well, your *outer* loop will still be handling `'bar'` *and try to remove it again*.

Comment: Ah, I understand what you're saying now. I'll edit my code to reflect those changes. Thanks for your help @Martijn